# checkboxes on layered navigation in the filter block

Tags: layered-navigation, filter, filtered-nav

which core files (controller,model and resource files) specifically needs to be edited to add check-boxes on layered navigation in the filter block in Magento.

What I have done till now is that I have added check-boxes and a JavaScript file which extracts ids of the products and then sends them via GET parameter to the controller.

I am not able to proceed beyond this since I am new Developer and do not know how is the controll passed and handled.

so, I want to know which all files do I need to override to make this feature functional?

Answer (score 3):

1. Log into admin panel and go to `System > Configuration`
2. Select the `Main website or your current store as Current Configuration Scope`
3. Select `Developer` tab under `ADVANCED` section
4. Click on `debug section` and set `Template Path Hints to yes` and `Add Block Names to Hints to yes`
5. Refresh the cache ( go to System > Cache Management )
6. Refresh the front-end
7. Now you'll see the relevant files to be overridden

Answer (score 3):

in this file all code make as ul li tag you have to just add checkbox on before that link display it's very simple task.

For that three `.phtml` files is use , the path is:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer

1) filter.phtml

2) state.phtml

3) view.phtml
```

you have to change the checkbox code in this 3 files

Make sure that this is in base folder but you have to copy this files in theme folder and do changes.

Comment: Athough the solution suggested is good, but i am not able to keep the filter on page as i select any one from them. On selecting any filter it moves to the state Block. So, what do i do to keep it from moving to the state?

Answer (score 1):

I override the code:
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\filter.phtml

Please check my code in github:

https://github.com/ronaldduque24/filter

Thank you